# Complex circular dependency

Tags: c++, oop, circular-dependency

what is the the best practice of solving circular dependency in `C++`?

I could use the forward declaration, but then I get the `pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed` error. Does that mean that two classes that uses each others pointer cannot be dependent?

Also, I thought about forward declaring each class and then including every header of the solution in the `main.cpp`, so it's all in one place. Would you recommend it?

A snippet from the whole project is below, so you can refer to it if the issue is better explained on an example I'm familiar with, but it would do just to be theoretical.
Thanks

[image: Models depending on each other]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to use forward declaration correctly:

1. Put all code in cpp files
2. Put just class declaration in header file
3. In header file:

   1. Use forward declaration if you only use a pointer or a reference.
   2. Otherwise you to include header file. (**Do Not** add unrequired includes)
4. In cpp file

   1. include all header files you require.

Note: Add include guards.

Its hard to actually do it without the actual declarations. The diagram is nice but does not have enough information. A picture may be worth a thousand words, but a precisely defined language can convey more exact information very compactly (unlike English and its inconsistencies).

Comment: Oh, you are right sir! Thanks a million for preventing my solution become bloated with interfaces. Works like a charm. Just a follow up: doesn't this procedure fail at step 3 if two classes depend on each other by value?

Comment: @Mikulas Dite: Think of situation were that could happen. Try and do it in a single file and you will also fail. This is a recursive dependency (you can do it with one class as well Class X has a member of type X. Or class X has a member of type Y and class Y has a member of type X. The language does not support this type of construct).

Comment: I guess I should have given it a thought before. You are right, such a construct does not really make sense.

Answer (score 7):

One thought is to introduce interfaces and remove the circular dependencies.  So you would have an IEffect that Effect, Player, and EffectContainer depend on.  Possibly, if Player depends on certain behavior of Effect and EffectContainer depends on a different set of behavior, I would consider introducing two interfaces, effectively following the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf). This would also follow along with the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, it did not occurred to me that this can be solved in such a clean way.

Comment: I've selected this answer at first, but as @Martin pointed out, properly set includes and forward declarations can handle this too, without bloating the code with interfaces and my vote goes to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is implemented by having every header file pre-declare the classes that it needs *before* its `#include`.  Additionally, no code should be put in the header files.  So you end up with:

```
class Effect;
class Player;
class GameStack;

#include <vector>
// more includes

class EffectContainer { ... }
```

and the equivalent in each place.  Then in your `.cpp` files you actually `#include` the headers for the other classes.  This will work if your objects don't have a circular dependency on the memory layout of the other classes.  Meaning that the methods and members can only refer to the other classes by reference or by pointer (but not by value).  This can get a little squirrelly if you have things like

```
 class EffectContainer {
   std::Vector<Effect> effects;
 }

 class Effect {
   boost::shared_ptr<EffectContainer> parent;
 }
```

as the template expansion sometimes requires full types and not merely pre-declared types.  One way many libraries avoid this issue is with a pointer to private impl pattern (often referred to as a PIMPL pattern), where every class is defined as:

```
class FooImpl;
class Foo {
  FooImpl* impl;
}
```

then the `FooImpl` is defined entirely in the `.cpp` file and your circularity issues can be ducked.  This design is also valuable because it maintains binary compatibility across releases of your library.  It does get a bit verbose, but nobody said `C++` was a succinct language.

Comment: Just for reference, since I do not believe Matt mentioned the name, this is generally referred to a the PIMPL idiom.  You can find numerous articles with a google search that will explain how it works in detail.

Comment: Good catch, I did provide the expansion "pointer to private impl" but forgot to mention the short name.

Comment: Thanks, yet I will stick with interfaces for now. This seems very similar, however.