# friend declaration block an external function access to the private section of a class

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

I'm trying to force function caller from a specific class.
For example this code bellow demonstrate my problem.
I want to make 'use' function would be called only from class A.
I'm using a global namespace all over the project.

*a.h*

```
#include "b.h"
namespace GLOBAL{

class A{
public:
    void doSomething(B);
}
}
```

*a.cpp*

```
#include "a.h"
using namespace GLOBAL;

void A::doSomething(B b){

    b.use();
}
```

*b.h*

```
namespace GLOBAL{

class B{
public:
    friend void GLOBAL::A::doSomething(B);
private:
    void use();
}
```

Compiler says:

```
‘GLOBAL::A’ has not been declared

‘void GLOBAL::B::use()’ is private
```

Can anyone help here ?

Thanks a lot,

Mike.

Comment: The declaration and definition of the `A::doSomething` function don't match (`int` vs. `B` argument types)

Comment: You also have a circular include problem here ...

Comment: What is with C+_+ is it supposed to mean something or is it a typo.

Comment: it was my mistake the problem has nothing with the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles fine from a cpp file:

```
namespace GLOBAL
{
    class B;

    class A
    {
    public:
        void doSomething(B& b);
    };
};


namespace GLOBAL
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        friend void GLOBAL::A::doSomething(B&);
    private:
        void use()
        {
        }
    };
};

void GLOBAL::A::doSomething(B& b)
{
    b.use();
}
```

As best I can tell your problem arises from the fact that you include "b.h" from "a.h" that defines the B class before the A class is defined yet the B class makes a reference to the A class.  So you have problems.  However you can't forward declare an object of type B because you are copying via the stack. Hence why I use a reference to class B (as this doesn't require the B object to be known in advance).

Basically you have some fundamental problems with your structure that needs working out.  You need to do some reading up on [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) and [circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency)

**Edit**: Specifying purely that class A is a friend of B (rather than a specific function in A that references B) is actually a possibility as the friend definition provides a kind of forward declaration.  As such the following code compiles:

```
namespace GLOBAL
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        friend class A;
    private:
        void use()
        {
        }
    };
};

namespace GLOBAL
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        void doSomething(B b);
    };
};

void GLOBAL::A::doSomething(B b)
{
    b.use();
}
```

As such in your code, originally posted, chaging the friend statement to, simply

```
friend class A;
```

should allow your code to compile.

Comment: I've requirements and must stick to that.
What other ways are suggested to implement a restricted call function ?

Comment: Basically if you have to pass B without reference or not as a pointer there is nothing you can do as far as i can see.  The code is very broken and can't possibly work because of the circular dependency alone.

Comment: It will if you haven't failed to forward declare and got your circular dependencies messed up.

Comment: is it possible to declare a friend class who will be able to
get to private section and at base class inherit this class
and manipulate the access ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because in the friend delcaration you are refering to a member of a class.

For this to work the compiler must already have seen the full definition of A.

#### a.h

```
// #include "b.h"   // remove this line it is not needed.
namespace GLOBAL{

class B; // Forward declare the class here.

class A{
public:
    void doSomething(B&); // Note: This should probably be a reference.
                          // Change to doSomething(B&); 
}
}
```

#### b.h

```
// Add this line it is needed for the friend declaration.
// To have a member as a friend we need the definition of 'A'
#include "a.h"

namespace GLOBAL{

class B{
public:
    friend void GLOBAL::A::doSomething(B&);
private:
    void use();
}
```

#### a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
// Add this line to include the B definition so you know how to call use()
#include "b.h"
using namespace GLOBAL;

void A::doSomething(B& b){ // b should be a reference otherwise you are copying it.

    b.use();
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to add the `#include "b.h"` into `a.cpp`, because there it is needed (to be able to call b.use).

Comment: I can't change include because I've more functions using other types.
it must be this way.

Comment: @user1697294: The requirement is that at the point of the friend declaration the compiler must have already seen a complete definition of the class A. If you can't change the include(s) then you have a problem. Otherwise it is fixed by the above. See also [Complex circular dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5364069/14065) for cleaning up your dependencies.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Thanks for pointing that out (it was cut and paste from the original question). But makes it clearer what the problem was. Fixed with a forward declaration.

Comment: Um, the `#include "a.h"` in `b.h` should be **outside** the `GLOBAL` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Move `#include "b.h"` from `a.h` to `a.cpp` after the first `#include` directive. The compiler doesn't need to see the friend declaration until it's compiling the function that the declaration applies to.

Comment: @JanHudec - so you downvoted because I explained why the include directive was misplaced?

Comment: can't do that because of the declaration:

void doSomething(B);

Comment: @MiP - forward declare `B` and pass it by `const&`.

Comment: I downvoted, because the answer is wrong. The compiler complains that it does not see enough and you suggest moving the directive to smaller scope (from `a.h` to `a.cpp` is smaller scope). That's not going to help. And yes, the compiler is complaining that it does not see enough -- namespaces and types need to be declared to be able to mention their members. Anywhere, always, because C++ syntax is ambiguous without knowledge what is namespace and what is type.

Comment: @JanHudec - sigh. The answer is incomplete, as illustrated by the subsequent comments.

Comment: Incomplete answer is wrong. Complete it or delete it. Besides I don't see any comments on this answer that would complete it -- and comments elsewhere are irrelevant; in such case this answer is just redundant. Yes, I am aware the change is needed as part of correct solution, but no, that does not make the answer correct, because it does not include the important part.

Comment: @JanHudec - no, I'll just leave it with your downvote and you non-explanations. That, along with your constructive suggestion for another incomplete answer, says all that needs to be said.

Comment: Upon compiling `b.h` (included from say, `c.cpp`, which does not need and thus does not include `a.h`; you have to get that implicit cases too) complains about that `GLOBAL::A` has not been declared on line 6. This answer says nothing about that problem. Yes, in `a.cpp`, if you include `a.h` and than `b.h`, it will compile, but it will appear again when somebody tries to use `B` and includes `b.h` only. So no, that's not a solution.

Comment: @JanHudec - it answers the question that was asked. Your insistence that you would have answered differently doesn't change that, nor does it make you an authority on how best to help beginners.